# Change the activity name to the right?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working in app but the language will be Arabic even the Activity name.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pleas don’t post code as picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean how to enable RTL support for your application?

In order to support RTL in your app, you first need to add android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in your manifest file.

If you want to force any layout to LTR then just add android:layoutDirection="ltr" to that view.

It's also recommended that you use "start" and "end" instead of "left" and "right" when designing your layouts.

Answer (score 1):

To show `activity` name to right in *RTL* language, you have to change the device language to *RTL*

Change the Display Language:

1. Tap the **Settings** app
2. Tap the "**Language & input**" option
3. Tap the "**Language**" option
4. Select any **RTL** language [Arabic] from the list of languages.

Check more details [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-Arabic-Language-on-Android)